# How to plot the number of Mersenne Primes lower than a given input?

Tags: plotting, number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to plot the number of Mersenne primes (primes of the form $2^n-1$) lower than a given input. I am totally noob to mathematica and I do not know where to start from. 
I have tried to implement "Range[ ]" and "Length@" functions, but I do not really know how to properly use then.
Thank you

Edit:
I am trying this code:

```
MersennePrimes[n_] := With[{primes = Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]]}, Length@Pick[primes, MersennePrimeExponentQ[n]]];
```

But i get this error:

```
Length::argx: Length called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
```

Any help?

Comment: Well, the documentation is generally a good place to start . Both https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MersennePrimeExponent.html may be useful for what you're trying to do.

Comment: While this is very easy to accomplish in Mathematica, before anyone takes the time to construct something for you, you should post some of what you've tried so far. Knowing which part of the process you're struggling with will help us better address the issues you've ran into.

Comment: @user6014 Thank you! Main post edited

Comment: @user3141592 I understand that you don't know how to use those functions, but if I were you I would try to read the manual and see if you can figure those out. You might also be interested in `PrimeQ`, or in `MersennePrimeExponentQ` from the documentation.

Comment: Furthermore, I would look to reformulate your question to clarify exactly what you're looking for. "I would like to plot the number of Mersenne primes (primes of the form 2n−1) lower than a given input." So you want to plot a single number? What does that accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Here's a hint for a simple implementation that counts the number of Mersenne primes less than a given number. You can use `Count` where the first argument to `Count` is `Range[ ...something... ]` and the second argument uses `MersennePrimeExponentQ`.

Comment: Dear @ChipHurst . I have updated my question with the information given. May you please help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

### Method

There are $44$ Mersenne primes implemented in *Mathematica*. Their exponents are instantly returned with (the [few more tentative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersennePrime.html) ones can be added to this list manually)

```
exp = MersennePrimeExponent @ Range @ 44
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203,
>   2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689, 9941, 11213, 19937, 21701, 23209,
>   44497, 86243, 110503, 132049, 216091, 756839, 859433, 1257787,
>   1398269, 2976221, 3021377, 6972593, 13466917, 20996011, 24036583,
>   25964951, 30402457, 32582657}

Mersenne primes are of the form $2^n-1$; one *could* compute them all with `2^exp-1`, but the 44th Mersenne prime has nearly 10 million digits, so I don't recommend it (MMA **can** handle their display, though). Nevertheless, *because* they are of the form $2^n-1$, which is a monotonic function, it is sufficient to translate `x` - i.e., the input smaller of which you want to find the number of primes - to `Log2[x + 1]`.

### Function

One can make a function:

```
f[x_] := Count[exp, u_ /; u < Log2[x + 1]]
```

Then:

```
f[2]
```

> 0

```
f[3]
```

> 0

```
f[10]
```

> 2

```
f[100]
```

> 3

```
f[100000]
```

> 5

```
f[131071]
```

> 5

```
f[131072]
```

> 6

and for example

```
f[123456789987623456789876523456785432123456789]
```

> 12

### Plotting

```
plot1 = LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, 1, 10^20},  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Full];
plot2 = LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, 1, 10^300}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Full];
GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

The horizontal axis displays the **exponent** for the prime in `Log10` basis. MMA is not able to go higher than the range showed in `plot2`. Note that, as mentioned,

```
Log10[2^Last[N @ exp]]
```

> 9.80835709543099*10^6

meaning that the 44th Mersenne prime has almost 10 million digits, being ridiculously big.